# Conditional breakpoint in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, conditional-breakpoint

I want to set a breakpoint on a certain line in C# code when some other variable is equal to a specific value, say:

```
MyStringVariable == "LKOH"
```

How can I do that?

I tried to right click on breakpoint icon -> Condition and then typed `MyStringVariable == "LKOH"` and Visual Studio said it cannot evaluate it.

Comment: I would normally modify code and inject code like

if(MyStringVariable = "LKOH")
{
 int a=1; // dummy code to set breakpoint
}

Comment: EDIT - change = to ==. THis was just a typo. Of course I used == in debugger

Comment: Oh another clue. Actually I am using a property. My true expression is

Exchange.Name == "LKOH", where Name is property. May be debugger cannot work with properties?

Comment: Expiremented. Conditions works for local variables, do not work
for class properties. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. Conditions work for class instance properties. See my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  string myvar;
  for (int ix = 0; ix < 10; ++ix) {
    if (ix == 5) myvar = "bar"; else myvar = "foo";
  }    // <=== Set breakpoint here
}
```

Condition: myvar == "bar"

Works well.

Answer (score 37):

`if (MyStringVariable == "LKOH") Debugger.Break();`

you'll need System.Diagnostics namespace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Just like in code, you need to use:

```
MyStringVariable == "LKOH"
```

The double-equals is the key.  Without it, it's saying it can't evaluate because your expression doesn't evaluate to a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to make this work. Are you using the Exchange instance name in the condition? The condition should be something like `myExchange.Name == "LKOH"` not `Exchange.Name == "LKOH"`.

By the way, using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==` will work but it will set the property and waste 1/2 hour of your time figuring out what the hell is going on. I made this mistake just yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I forgot that I was debugging a VB application.

In VB equality is `=` not `==` like many other languages, thus my conditional breakpoint needed to be `myString = "someValue"` not `myString == "someValue"`

Answer (score 1):

The variable you are testing for needs to be in scope at the breakpoint.

```
var x = "xxx";
{ 
  var y = "yyy";
}

brak(); // x is in scope, y isn't
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this made it hit the conditional breakpoint.

[image: Conditional breakpoint]